# Disable trace logging for tracer package for ElasticSearch Java Rest Client

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-commons, apache-commons-logging

I am doing a bulk indexing operation through ElasticSearch 6.3 Java Rest Client.

Data is getting indexed correctly however restclient is printing extensive logs in the file. see below:

```
2018-08-14 16:25:42,614 DEBUG [User=] [tracer] curl -iX POST 'http://1.2.3.4:9202/_bulk?timeout=1m' -d '{"create":{"_index":"ms","_type":"doc","_id":"24218000","version":-4}}
{"create":{"_index":"ms","_type":"doc","_id":"24217999","version":-4}}
{"data":"test","year":2018,"corrid":"24217999","mode":"USPS","emailaddress":"","mimeType":"application/octet-stream","title":"some title","type":"app","maildate":"2018-01-02","code":"abx","direction":"out","quarter":0,"no":"222876"}
{"create":{"_index":"ms","_type":"doc","_id":"24218345","version":-4
```

How can I disable or limit this?

[This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-logging.html) document talks about a little bit, but does not give enough information about it clearly.

Comment: What's the logging library of your application? I would suspect that you have it set to `DEBUG` globally, but you want to set `org.elasticsearch.client` only to `INFO` or `WARN`. Depending on your log appender, you need to set this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that their documentation is vague.

It sounds like you have an entry like

```xml
<logger name="tracer" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>
```

or

```
tracer.level=TRACE
```

somewhere in `commons-logging` configuration being imported. At the very least, I think you can set the level to `WARN` or `ERROR` to quiet the chatter.

As xeraa mentioned, you may also have logger levels set too high for `org.elasticsearch.client`, `org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient`, `org.elasticsearch.client.sniffer`, etc.